# Is it possible to use Google Container Builder with GitLab

Tags: gitlab, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I can see options for Cloud Source Repository, GitHub and Bitbucket, but is it possible to use a git repo from my private Gitlab server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported at this time.

Answer (score 4):

It looks feasible to have Gitlab [*push*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) to a mirror GCP Cloud Repository, which can then be used for Cloud Builder Build Triggers.

Seeing as Cloud Builder's github/bitbucket integration is basically a pull mirror, I doubt you would be losing much if anything by using Gitlab with it.

> After you've set up your external repository, Cloud Source Repository creates a mirror of your repository. https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/how-to/build-triggers#creating_a_build_trigger